# How do I access the value of an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the o2 and o3 objects, I know I can access the bar keys by using this.bar, but how do i access foo?

```
 function foo(){
 console.log(this.bar);
 }

 var bar = "bar1";

 var o2 = {bar:"bar2", foo:foo};
 var o3 = {bar:"bar3", foo:foo};



 foo();
 o2.foo();
 o3.foo();
```

Comment: Exactly the way your code already does access "foo". It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: why does this.foo not work?

Comment: Your code does not call `this.foo()` anywhere.

Comment: console.log(this) will show you why

Answer (score 1):

> but how do i access foo

`this.foo` can be used inside the `foo` function, or just `foo` since the function is available from the variable scope too.

So if you did `this.foo()`, you'd get the value of the `bar` property of the `this` object, but if you did `foo()`, you'd get the `bar` variable, if it's in the global scope.

Either way, be aware that if you invoke `foo` from inside `foo`, it'll be a recursive call with no escape clause, and you'll exceed the stack limit.

---

> why does this.foo not work?

If you do it outside the `foo` function, it will work *as long as* the `foo` function was defined in the global scope. If the `foo` function is in a local scope, then `this.foo()` will not see it.